# Implementing multiple navigation actions on a single menuitem button in Kotlin(android)

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface

I am trying to implement a way for the `menuitem` button to navigate to a different fragment based on the current fragment.

For example, if I am in the `fragment_home`, I can access the `dog_fragment` and from the `dog_fragment` I can access another fragment like `cat_fragment`and vice versa.

So far I am only able to navigate from `fragment_home` to `dog_fragment`, however when I try to access any other fragments from the `dog_fragment` my app crash. If I try to access another fragment from any other fragment accept from the `home_fragment` my app crashes

```
//This is in the Mainactivity
fun onComposeAction(item: MenuItem) {
    val navHostFragment =
        supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainerView) as NavHostFragment
    val navController = navHostFragment.navController
    when (item.getItemId()) {
        R.id.Hamster -> {
            navController.navigate(R.id.action_home2_to_hamster)
            
        }
        R.id.Dog -> {
            navController.navigate(R.id.action_home2_to_dog)

        }
        R.id.Cat ->{
            navController.navigate(R.id.action_home2_to_cat)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your action is called `action_home2_to_hamster`, which sounds like it is an action specific to `home2` and not something you can call from every destination. Is there a reason you're not using the [built in support for tying menu items to destinations](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#Tie-navdrawer) or using [global actions](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-global-action) if you really insist on doing everything manually?

Comment: Hmmm alright then I will try it out

Comment: Solved it thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply tie the `menuitems` to the destination fragments you have.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).